# Py.test not recognizing pip installed packages

Tags: python, setuptools, pytest, setup.py

I followed this guide,
http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractices.html

And structured my project to resemble the second case,

```
setup.py   # your setuptools Python package metadata
mypkg/
    __init__.py
    appmodule.py
tests/
    test_app.py
    ...
```

I then integrated test runs into setup.py using the pytest-runner plugin,

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    #...,
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner', ...],
    tests_require=['pytest', ...],
    #...,
)
```

and my setup.cfg,

```
[aliases]
test=pytest
```

After running `pip install -e .` I can use `python setup.py test` to run tests; however, `py.test` (in the mypkg/ directory) doesn't work. I get an import error as appmodule isn't recognized.

Is this normal behavior? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong? If this is normal, then I can live with running `python setup.py test` in lieu of `py.test` but I figured that I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Please try to add the path to your project to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I'll try that when I get home but wouldn't that defeat the purpose for creating the setup.py? Also `python /tests/test_app.py` works, however,  `py.test` and `pytest tests/test_app.py` don't work. It seems that pytest, when ran as `py.test`, isn't recognizing the installed package.

Comment: Can you show the output of `which pip` and `which py.test`?

Comment: @TheCompiler I solved the problem with your help. Thanks! `which pip` confirmed that the pip is iside my virtual environment, however,`which py.test` revealed that pytest was installed globally. If I install pytest into my virtualenvironment, it works.

Comment: Things like that are why I usually do `python -m pip`/`python -m pytest`, or use the full path (`venv/bin/pip`, `venv/bin/py.test`) - then you can be sure.